# Android App size problem

Tags: android, size, apk, max

I have 11 videos to include in my App. Each of them is around 9MB. Besides those, I have to a few sound files and image files in the app. Therefore the app size is going 100+MB. Is there any way to accommodate all the files so that app size does not become an issue for me?

Comment: Download in first run after install. Video and Audio sizes cannot be decreased even after compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puh..that's quite large. In such a situation I'd

1. Let the user download your app not containing any videos/audio files that cause the large size
2. At first run guide the user through a wizard where you download the additionally needed files to the SD card.

Still, downloading nearly 100MB won't be ideal, but better than directly download all of it at the first install. (IMHO)

Answer (score 2):

Download the files after starting the app for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The most common sollution i've seen is downloading them during the first run of the programme. Just check if everything is available, and if it isn't, download the needed files.

pros:

- This way you can also add video's on the fly.
- APK size stays small so initial download is quick

Cons:

- after downloading the app you can't directly use it: content must be downloaded first

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put them in the `assets` folder, so they will not be compressed.

This way you'll have problems testing your project with eclipse, so try building it with command line, and then install on device with `adb`

In my scenario, I had 300+ videos, totalling upto 400+ MB of the size.
I checked with few of them and deployed the app the way i just told.

may not be the best way around, but may work.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload into youtube or make your own simple video streaming server